# CSS for Angular .cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper not applied

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I want to customize a [`<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview) by using the CSS class `.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper` so that the scroll container always shows a scrollbar. But my CSS code for this specific element is not applied (all other styles in the same component are working).

```
.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The behavior is not specific to this CSS property - if I set a border for example there is also no effect.

In the developer tools I can see the effective CSS, which lacks `overflow-y`:

```
.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    contain: content;
}
```

But if I change the CSS of the respective HTML element directly in the developer tools of the browser, the scroll bar is displayed.

Setting CSS for `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` or `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport > div` doesn't work either:

```
cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I'm using Angular 10.2.2 with Sass.

How to apply CSS to `.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper`?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

```css
::ng-deep .cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

### Update

as mentioned below, this can cause side effect, to isolate, add a css class like this:

```css
.you-class ::ng-deep .cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Editing angular material css is not so easy, but I find it easier to do so in you css file which is at the same level of your `index.html`. If you're inspecting element you'll find that sometimes styles are applied before your component. You also might need to use the `!important` css option.

Comment: I recommend reading a bit about ng-deep and its side effects and future compatibility, prior to copy-pasting the above snippet into your production code.

Comment: ::ng-deep is gonna be deprecated soon

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue trying to style the virtual scroll content wrapper in the scoped stylesheet(component level). Worked when I moved

```
.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
  // styles
}
```

to styles.scss

Answer (score 0):

For me, worked when I moved the cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper css code from the component css file to styles.css (same folder level as index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

to @Component declaration.